# Has the use of a radiator surface on the inside of duct ever been tried?

Tags: propeller, efficiency

I wonder if using radiating surface on the inside of a ducted fan to dispel the waste heat of an engine would provide an economic advantage by increasing thrust?  Since a typical engine “wastes” some 40% of its energy as heat could it not be used to expand the air going through the duct a little like a jet?

Answer (score 1):

That's basically what happens with the radiator on the P-51.  It uses the [Meredith effect](http://www.supercoolprops.com/home/articles/meredith_effect2.html) to use the heat from the radiator to provide a small amount of thrust.